# Visual Studio 2013 cannot open .coverage files

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have been trying to enable code coverage with Visual Studio 2013 (following [the command line version of these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd299398%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)) and it appears to work up until I try to open the generated .coverage file.  When VS2013 opens the coverage file it shows the binary as if the file type is not known.

The simplified instructions are:

1. Build binary with /PROFILE linker flag enabled
2. Run vsinstr.exe -coverage to instrument the build
3. Run 'Start vsperfmon -coverage -output:results.coverage'
4. Run 'vsperfcmd -shutdown'
5. Open results.coverage in Visual Studio

Everything works until the last step when VS2013 fails to recognize or parse the coverage file.  Does command line based code coverage work in VS2013?  I am using VS2013 Professional.

Comment: Actually it looks like it is unsupported in the professional edition : http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs.aspx